# How to create realtime sheets using drive realtime api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have gotten the Drive realtime API to work for docs, but I haven't found any references for sheets.

I have also been able to embed a sheet into the webpage, but it is uneditable.
How do I embed a collaborative realtime sheet?

Comment: What do you mean you got realtime to work with docs? Its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realtime API is for creating collaborative items using your own custom document type, not for editing the Google Documents/Spreadsheets/Presentations types.

If you want to edit those, you want to use [app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).