# Google Realtime API with Google Docs

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-drive-realtime-api

I would like to build an application on a webpage, that does as google docs:
I want to build an app that allow people to work on a document in collaboration
I start with this: https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart
But the problem is that it creates a file with the mimetype is "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk".

I would like to work with google docs format, so people can open them with their google drive and edit their later.

The file created is not the proper format, and find it me impossible to open it.
( I try to edit the mimetype with "application/vnd.google-apps.document", however it creates the file in the google drive but it can't find the file when it try to load it).

How to create a google doc in realtime ? (If you can post the code here, it would help me a lot)

Then, it want to add the toolbar for editing(bold, italic,...).
After that, it would like to add the google picker to select the file to load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create realtime sheets using drive realtime api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587009/how-to-create-realtime-sheets-using-drive-realtime-api)

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am getting an error 500 message returned when I attempt to load a Google Doc with the Realtime API.