# Google Drive API - PHP Deprecated version

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-api

I found the Quickstart guide to run a drive APP in PHP, https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php, but the example script is not working, because the new Github version has a different structure.

Where can I find the updated version of the example for the same purposes?
Or is there a similar one, for that exact github version (**google-api-php-client-master**)

I would love to create and edit google doc files.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find some examples in zip file.

Comment: Hi thanks! :D I already took a look at it, but didn't figure out how to create a realtime google doc editing app. Where can I find some info?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587009/how-to-create-realtime-sheets-using-drive-realtime-api

Comment: @user2511140 Thanks for you answer, but it's not really what I was looking for. Maybe I'm expressing myself wrong, because I do not really understand the difference. Suppose I have a Textarea with plain text on a website... I just want that anybody can edit the same textarea (in plain text) in realtime. I've seen an example here (https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart) but it doesn't work (see problem on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785746/realtime-drive-javascript-example-not-working-google-api)

Comment: - Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it. Sorry if I'm a little confused about terms, it's a quite wide thing this drive api.