# Realtime drive javascript example not working - Google API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I set up the Realtime drive example shown here: https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart

On this site: http://shuub.com

But the thing is, that when I access the link from a different browser (logged in a different Google account), it won't load the file.

All I need is to edit some plain text with another user, without needing to access a google account, **it doesn't even need to be saved after closing the site**. Is it possible?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the thing is, that when I access the link from a different browser
>   (logged in a different Google account), it won't load the file.

Probably you need to share the file with the other user first.

Open [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/) in your Browser. If you did not modify the example code, your file should be located in the root folder. It's probably named "New Realtime Quickstart File". Right-click on the file and share it with the other user by adding his account to the list and granting all permissions.

> All I need is to edit some plain text with another user, without
>   needing to access a google account, it doesn't even need to be saved
>   after closing the site. Is it possible?

The website you have linked is not reachable so I don't know what you want to do exactly.
Probably you could also use other and (in that use case without saving and login) simpler techniques like [Mozillas TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/) (you can try it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)) or you could use a tool like [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/).